# Can I have more than 4 players on a GameCenter game?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, game-center

I am fiddling around with making a simple multiplayer game using Game Center.  I am using Apple's code.  I just changed the number of max players to 5 instead of 2:

```
- (void)hostMatch:(id)sender
{
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 5;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I have `request.maxPlayers` equal to 2-4 it works fine, but once I go over 5 it gives me this error:

`The requested operation could not be completed because the match request is invalid.`

Has anyone figured out a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

It all depends to the type of the game you are creating. The below table is from apple doc's:

> Table 7-3
>
> Maximum number of players for each kind of match
>
> Match Type.       Maximum Number of Players
>
> Peer-to-Peer       4
>
> Hosted.            16
>
> Turn-based.        16

Here is the link for further study: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW7

Comment: I would like to do a Hosted game.  I saw that there is a GKTurnBasedMatch.h that I could use instead of GKMatch.h, but I haven't found anything for a Hosted Match.  Do you know how I can do a Hosted Match?

Comment: This might be too late, but GKMatchmakerViewController has a hosted property, if you set that to YES, it'll be a hosted match